# Problem Interacting With Mojang Authentication Server

Tags: node.js, https, minecraft

I am trying to get a client token from the Mojang Authentication API, which can be found here https://wiki.vg/Authentication. However, whenever I try to make a request, I get the following response:
`{error: 'ForbiddenOperationException', errorMessage: 'Forbidden'}`
The API indicates this is because my credentials are invalid but the errorMessage that I am getting does not match any of their examples. I tried doing the same request through python's Requests module, and it worked well, which leads me to believe I am not sending my https request properly. I am aware there is probably something very basic I am overlooking, but I would appreciate it if someone tells me what I am doing wrong.
Here is my code:

Python Code that works:

```py
import requests

url = 'https://authserver.mojang.com/authenticate'
data = {"username":"--username--", "password":"--password--"}
res = requests.post(url, json=data)
print(res.json())
```

Javascript Code that Doesn't Work:

```js
var https = require('https');

var options = {
    host: 'authserver.mojang.com',
    path: '/authenticate',
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {"username":"--username--","password":"--password--"}
}

https.request(options, (res)=>{
    var body = ''
    res.on('data', (d)=>{
        body+=d;
    });
    res.on('end', ()=>{
        resp = JSON.parse(body);
        console.log(resp);
    });
}).end();
```

Comment: Please post your Requests code too, so we can see what you're doing differently to break it.

Comment: I added the requests code. I believe something is wrong with the https options, probably the headers, but I'm not too familiar with https and am not sure what it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you're sending your credentials as HTTP headers directly instead of as POST data. Try this instead:

```js
var https = require('https');

var data = JSON.stringify({"username":"--username--","password":"--password--"})

var options = {
    host: 'authserver.mojang.com',
    path: '/authenticate',
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Content-Length': data.length
    }
}

var req = https.request(options, (res)=>{
    var body = ''
    res.on('data', (d)=>{
        body+=d;
    });
    res.on('end', ()=>{
        resp = JSON.parse(body);
        console.log(resp);
    });
});
req.write(data);
req.end();
```